# android list item selector and divider

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a ListView with a custom divider. Divider is just some color and is 3dp in height.
I've added a custom selector to each item in the list, so the background color would be changed when item is clicked. My selector looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">:
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

When item is selected, it changes color from grey to yellow as expected.
However, the color of all dividers in the list changes as well. Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in your example you are not written the false states in selector. This may be the issue. Try writing a complete selector XML like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">:
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

Comment: if the state isn't selected, doesn't selector choose the default state, which has grey as a background?

Comment: @Maggie It's supposed to work this way. That's also how Google explains it in its documentation and videos. How come it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure, but maybe you set your divider the same drawable, I am posting a code which will help you to change the color of your divider.
something like this .

```
android:divider="#FFCC00"
android:dividerHeight="4px"
```

Comment: His question already contain: *Divider is just some color and is 3dp in height.*

Comment: yes, I know but I said, maybe he set the divider="@drawable/somedrabale" , that's why i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable default divider and make custom divider as a part of list item's background (probably using 9-patch).

Comment: His question already contain: *Divider is just some color and is 3dp in height.*

Comment: I know, I am just providing my favorite way to do that. Because usually you need to have nicer divider (e.g. from graphic designer).

Answer (score 0):

Add custom selector in listselector like

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"/>
```